# Load a Page with Ajax and sent Data to the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I generate a javascript Array and I want to send it to the `berechnungsauswertung.php` page and load that page. And than I want to use the data at this page in php.

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'berechnungsauswertung.php',
        data : {
            marker : JSON.stringify(data),
            homemarker : JSON.stringify(datahome)
        },
        complete : function(data){
            $('body').load( "berechnungsauswertung.php" );               
        }
    });
```

on the next page I want to get the Variables

```
$marker = json_decode($_POST['marker']);
$homemarker = json_decode($_POST['homemarker']);
```

but it does not work. How can I load a Page like this?

Comment: Why are you loading the page twice?

Comment: @SLaks What do you mean with twice?

Comment: Once from `$.ajax()` and once from `$.load()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are doing:

1. Make Ajax request with POST data
2. Ignore the response
3. Make Ajax request without any data
4. Include the content in the page

It doesn't work because you don't have the data from 1 when you are loading the new content in 4.

Replace your `complete` function with a `success` function. Do something with the data you get (the first argument to the success function) such as passing it to `jQuery('something').html(data)`.

Don't use `load` at all.

Comment: Thank you, can I cange the urle somehow to www.page/berechnungsauswertung.php